# Music players don't see my music

Tags: music

I loaded a bunch of music onto my Samsung Galaxy 6.  The songs are there because I can find them using MyFiles and can click on them to play them individuals.  However, every music player app I have tried does not see these files so I have no control over them to do things like create playlists.  In the MyFiles app they are in a folder called Audio and all mixed together.  DeviceStorage/Music contains the actual CD names but when those folders are opened in music apps, it says no files. I can actually play them from the Samsung MUSIC app but bizarrely this is accomplished by selecting "Verizon Cloud" from the menu and it is always going on about "waiting for backup".  I have tried 4 different music apps and none of them seem to be able to locate my Audio folder which I see in MyFiles.

Comment: What about google play music

Comment: Note to future readers: Depending on how the songs were copied, the media scanner might not yet have cataloged them – so music players relying on its catalog won't see them. Easiest way to fix that is rebooting your device, as at boot is one of the times where it definitely runs the scan. Factory reset should not be needed; it would also delete all contents and thus not be really helpful ;)